# Updating large dataframe using numpy where

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm have a large dataframe, over 2 million records and 9 columns wide. I need to create a column and fill this with data derived from another column. This is what I have so far. I am using a numpy "where" to query one column and if it finds the matching string to update another column.
There are a number of these "where" statements, over 30 of them, but for brevity I have only shown one as an example.

```
user_d["renamed"] = np.where(user_d.ActDescript.str.contains("Organise & Busin"), "Organisation & Business Name Search","Not Found")
```

This works fine up to a point. The issue I am having is when I run these "where" functions altogether I get a memory error. At first I thought I could split up the "where" statements to say run 10 at a time.
The dataframe updates as I expected.
However when I run the next 10 statements through the same dataframe the updates from the first run are overwritten.
I'm looking for a solution where I can perhaps run these multiple "where" statements as one whole block without the memory errors or to run them 10 at a time with the previous update being overwritten.

Any help would be grateful.

thanks

Comment: If other "where"  conditions makes new columns as strings, you can convert them to `category`  data type like this:
`user_d["renamed"] = user_d["renamed"].astype('category')`
`category` datatype under hood convert strint values to integer, what reduce memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to find out what the underlaying problem is without further code or info. My best guess would be that as **AlexanderS** said in the comments, you are creating new column on top of the already existing columns, which needs memory.
On top of that the new column contains plain strings which are not memory optimized. Here a comparison of size and possible solutions:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd

# byte size: plain string
s = "Organisation & Business Name Search"
sys.getsizeof(s)
# 84

# byte size: boolean
sys.getsizeof(True)
# 28

# Worst -> Store categorical data, e.g. 2 kind of strings as plain strings.
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [s for x in range(1, 1000)]})
sys.getsizeof(df["col1"])
# 66.078

# Better -> Store categorical data, e.g. 2 kind of strings as Pandas Categorical.
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [s for x in range(1, 1000)]})
df["col1"] = pd.Categorical(df["col1"])
sys.getsizeof(df["col1"])
# 1.317

# Best -> Store categorical data, e.g. 2 kind of strings as boolean.
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [x >= 500 for x in range(1, 1000)]})
sys.getsizeof(df["col1"])
# 1.143
```